# What to do when losing a receipt with credit card information

Tags: credit-card, security, mexico

A good friend of mine went to a store to buy some stuff, and he paid for it with his card. For some reason the ticket contained my friend's name, credit card number and signature. My friend is wondering whether he should cancel the card.

Does the loss of information warrant my friend cancelling his card?

Comment: What country are you in?  It would be highly unusual for a receipt to contain an entire CC number.

Comment: It doesn't relate to answering your question, but what country did this purchase take place in? It is illegal for more than the last 4 or 5 digits to be displayed in the US.

Comment: Mexico, and yes, it had the full number, Although he already cancelled it. I also had never seen something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend having the bank issue a new card and also explain to the bank what happened. It's very likely that the vendor your friend made the purchase at is violating the rules regarding credit card security, and his bank would be privy to those regulations. He could save others from potential fraud by being the one to get that business to change their receipt layout.

[Here in the U.S. it violates Federal Law](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/slip-showing-federal-law-requires-all-businesses-truncate) to print a non-truncated version of the credit card number on a receipt and can result in a business no longer being allowed to accept credit cards at all.

> According to the federal Fair and Accurate Credit Transaction Act
>   (FACTA), the electronically printed credit and debit card receipts you
>   give your customers must shorten — or truncate — the account
>   information. You may include no more than the last five digits of the
>   card number, and you must delete the card’s expiration date.